# How to design a table where it self-referencs and the order doesn't matter

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Say I have a list of users, and I want to record hand shaking between them:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(70)
);

CREATE TABLE hand_shaking (
    user1 INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES user,
    user2 INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES user
);
```

The `user` table has data like:

```
1,Sarah
2,John
3,Alex
```

and the `hand_shaking` table can have data like:

```
1,2
```

which means Sarah and John shook hands.

Now the question is that how should I design the `hand_shaking` table so that duplicates won't be allowed? For example, if `1,2` is already inserted, `2,1` should fail.

I'm using postgresql, and I tried to declare `PRIMARY KEY(user1, user2)` on the `hand_shaking` table, but `2,1` is still allowed after `1,2` has been inserted.

Comment: I probably need a better title for this question, but at the moment I have no idea how to accurately describe it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique index that indexes the same values for the two different combinations:

```
create unique index only_one_handshake 
    on hand_shaking (least(user1,user2), greatest(user1,user2));
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the `id` column is of a type like `uuid`? Is there a general solution or it will depend on the type of the primary key?

Comment: This works with any data type that supports comparison operators like `>` - so essentially everything except `bytea`

Comment: Got it. Really appreciate your help. It got me thinking though, what if there are three parties involved? like a "which three users met each other" kind of relationship. How should the unique index be created in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can build your check logic using arrays, Eg:

```
t=# create table so27 (a text,b text, c text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so27 select 'a','b','c';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so27 select 'a','b','d';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so27 select 'c','a','b';
INSERT 0 1
t=# select *,'{b,c,a}'::text[] @> ('{}'::text[]||a||b||c)::text[] from so27;
 a | b | c | ?column?
---+---+---+----------
 a | b | c | t
 a | b | d | f
 c | a | b | t
(3 rows)
```